# Unexpected outcome with System.out.println

Tags: java

I'm in the process of making a program using input from a text file, it only has 2 lines of text in it which is

- 120 (this is the time)
- 2 (this is changes)

My code is meant to read the user's input which converts hours to minutes, and then asks for a number of changes. If the hours entered are 02:00 which is 120 minutes and the changes entered are 2 or less then it will come back saying 'acceptable', and if not it will read 'unacceptable' however I am having a bit of trouble formulating this. If anybody could provide assistance I would appreciate it greatly!

Code to follow:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputOutput {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    final Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    final Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("task.txt"));

    // open file and associate objects
    int IOminutes = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());
    int changes = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());

    // close the input file
    inFile.close();

    System.out.print("Specify Time (HH:MM): ");
    String givenTime = S.next();

    System.out.print("Specify Changes: ");
    String givenChanges = S.next();

        // save the index of the colon
        int colon = givenTime.indexOf(':');

        // strip the hours preceding the colon then convert to int      
        int givenHours = Integer.parseInt(givenTime.substring(0, colon));

        // strip the mins following the colon then convert to int
        int givenMins = Integer.parseInt(givenTime.substring(colon + 1, givenTime.length()));

        // calculate the time's total mins
        int mins = (givenHours * 60) + givenMins;

        // using given time
        System.out.println(givenTime + " = " + mins + " minutes");

            if (!givenTime.equals(IOminutes) && changes >= 3) {
                System.out.println("Time: " + givenTime + ", Changes: " + givenChanges + " = unacceptable!");
            } else if (givenTime.equals(IOminutes) && changes <= 2) {
                System.out.println("Time: " + givenTime + ", Changes: " + givenChanges + " = acceptable!");
            }
        S.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the unexpected output? Is it possible to make the question more understandable?

Comment: Yes! Of course, sorry about that. Basically, when you start the program, you are asked to input a time in the format HH:MM so it can convert it to minutes. In the text file I am accessing there is a line with 120 in for 120 minutes, so if you enter 2:00 that'd be 120 minutes. The user also enters a number of changes, in the text file there is another line which is '2'. When the user enters 2:00 or below for the time and 2 or below for the changes, it'll come back as 'acceptable', anything other than this is 'unacceptable' if this makes sense?

Comment: This is unrelated, but just so you know, `S`, `inFile`, and `IOminutes` aren't following Java's [variable naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)...`S` should have a meaningful name, and since it's a static final, should be in all-caps, with words separated by "_" (underline); `inFile` should be `INPUT_FILE`, for similar reasons; `IOminutes` should be named simply `minutes`, or something like `parsedMinutes`.

Comment: Oh, thank-you @TheLima! I'm still learning so that's very helpful! I'll keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: "If the hours entered are 02:00 which is 120 minutes and the changes entered are 2 or less then it will come back saying 'acceptable'" Where is the line of code which does this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Supposedly, `givenTime.equals(IOminutes) && changes >= 3`...BTW lb, you only need one conditional there, with a simple `else` instead of an `else-if`

Comment: @TheLima that's what I am leading to, that not what this line does. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't have my NetBeans up...I'm working on a web app on webstorm right now, so I'm not really testing what the code does and I'm too lazy to *think* about it right now...But I can help the OP with the Java's basics...=P

Comment: @TheLima I know what you mean.  I suggest the OP write the code to match what he is say in English and this line does match what he is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs (file-based and user-based) look reasonable.
By the time you reach your if-elseif logic on line 40, you have the following values (all values based on the problem description in the question): 
loaded from "task.txt"...
    IOminutes: 120
    changes: 2

```
user input:
givenTime="02:00"
givenChanges=2
givenHours=2
givenMins=0
mins=2*60+0 = 120
```

Your conversion from strings to integers looks like no problem.

Your desired outcome of "acceptable" / "unacceptable" is hard for me to understand; not what it is doing, but Why it is doing that.
I'm having trouble understanding why you have two "changes".

This would make more sense to me if you just had:
    task.txt: IOminutes=120, changes=2
    given: time="hh:mm"
Now compute difference (in minutes) between task.txt's IOminutes and user's given time.  Let's call that difference givendiff.  Then you have something like:
    if givendiff > changes then unacceptable.

Examples (user input values more or less made up):

```
task.txt: IOminutes=120, changes=2
test 1: given time="02:00"  (computed givendiff=0,   so acceptable)
test 2: given time="01:50"  (computed givendiff=-10, so unacceptable)
test 3: given time="02:05"  (computed givendiff=5,   so unacceptable)
test 3: given time="02:02"  (computed givendiff=2,   so acceptable)
test 3: given time="01:58"  (computed givendiff=-2,  so acceptable)
```

I would encourage you to review the original requirements and verify whether your user is supposed to be give you an extra "changes" in addition to task.txt's changes.  Or if you're supposed to compute a the difference between task.txt's IOminutes and the user-entered value, and complain if that difference exceeds task.txt's changes value.

I would go further but this seems like a homework or code-challenge problem; if so, hopefully this is enough to help nudge your perspective to re-thing what "changes" means in the original requirements.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank-you very much! This actually helped a lot and proved to push me towards the answer, it's working now - thank-you very much!